# Usar comandos de cmd em scripts feitos para rodar em shell - cakephp 3.0

Tags: shell, cmd, cakephp-3

Eu queria saber se tem como usar comandos nativos do CMD do windows, apartir de scripts feitos para rodar no shell do cakephp.

Já executo tarefas que rodam no cmd, mas com os comandos do próprio framework mas gostaria de usar outros comandos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi bem a duvida, suponho que queira criar um Shell no cakephp, tal como:

```
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;

class HelloShell extends Shell
{
    public function main()
    {
        $this->out('Hello world.');
    }
}
```

Mas que ele execute comandos que existem na maquina.

> Entenda que os comandos que rodam no CMD são em sua maioria executáveis globais.

Para rodar comando do Windows você precisará obviamente estar em um servidor Windows e não necessáriamente irá precisar do cakephp, mas somente do php, no caso temos 3 funções:

- [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) - retorna a reposta do programa em uma referencia do tipo array (segundo parâmetro)
- [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) - retorna a resposta diretamente no output, ou se for HTTP já imprime como se fosse usado o `echo`, também é possível pegar a ultima linha do output e a resposta de retorno do aplicativo (geralmente é um numero)
- [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) - Executa um comando via "shell" e retorna o resultado um string

> É importante notar que se for usar argumentos nos comandos é necessário usar o [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) ou [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

```
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;

class HelloShell extends Shell
{
    public function main()
    {
        $resposta = shell_exec('dir');

        $this->out($resposta);
    }

    public function raiz()
    {
        $resposta = shell_exec('dir \\');

        $this->out($resposta);
    }

    public function foo($pasta)
    {
        $resposta = shell_exec('dir ' . $pasta);

        $this->out($resposta);
    }
}
```

Depois de salvar o arquivo, você deve ser capaz de executar os seguintes comandos:

- Exibe o conteúdo da pasta atual, geralmente a que chamou o script principal o variando do apontamento da aplicação maior (por exemplo apache):

  ```
  bin/cake hello
  ```
- Exibe o conteúdo da pasta raiz:

  ```
  bin/cake hello raiz
  ```
- Exibe o conteúdo de uma pasta que determinar:

  ```
  bin/cake hello foo /a/b/c
  ```

Eles irão mostrar algo como:

```
O volume na unidade C não tem nome.
O Número de Série do Volume é AEE4-3225

Pasta de C:\Users\Guilherme\Exemplo

18/08/2016  23:06    <DIR>          .
18/08/2016  23:06    <DIR>          ..
14/07/2016  23:14    <DIR>          pasta
28/04/2016  21:03                21 .bash_history
               1 arquivo(s)          21 bytes
              3 pasta(s)   267.064.922.112 bytes disponíveis
```